# WordPress Plugin with Widget in a single package

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I am trying to build a WordPress Plugin and Widget, and I would like them to be in the same physical package. The Widget should remain as typical WordPress widget that can be dragged-and-dropped into widget enabled areas (already done and working), and the Plugin should enable certain submenu in WordPress admin panel with few options there, and it should be able to render certain HTML in the main document; let's say *body* part.

I also want to make the two communicate; at least so that the Widget could read certain settings from the Plugin.

I am an advanced PHP programmer, but I'm still fairly new to WP plugin development, so my primary question is about suggested architecture for that. Couldn't Google anything interesting and I just don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

My trials and errors lead me to something like:

```
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget {
...
}
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("MyWidget");'));
```

And then:

```
class MyPlugin {
...
}
```

Both in main *plugin.php* file, but I'm still getting completely lost on both launching the latter and again any form of public-methods communication between the two.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [this](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204) as your basic plugin. Inside the `plugin_setup()`, call the Widget action (with an `include` to the widget class) and all the other plugin actions. Research the tag `<plugin-development>` at [wordpress.se], lots of good stuff, and more developers per square pixel than here ;) Extra: [(1)](https://github.com/Emerson/Sanity-Wordpress-Plugin-Framework) and [(2)](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

When working with classes in wordpress plugins 
instead of

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("MyWidget");'));
```

you would need to structure it like this

```
add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'callback');
```

yes, method without its variables, INSIDE quotations, use $this if the callback is iniside this class, but you can also use class $my_other_class instantiated with $my_other_class = new My_Other_Class(); to call a method inside $my_other_class ... also &$this will work (passing a reference)

furthermore, if you want to pass variables to your callback, you can add an action inside your callback method like so:

```
add_action('my_custom_hook'...
```

and then wherever your variables are you can

```
do_action('my_custom_hook', $var, $var2)
```

to make them accessible inside your callback function

hope this gives you a starting point at the very least on how to structure things within wp context...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time mate, but two things... First, it does not really answer my question on about loading two different things (Plugin and Widget) from one file. Second, I have came accross the approach you suggested, yet it somehow does not fire.
Does WordPress have some sort of class autoloader there anyway?